# NodeJS+ Mongo создание облака

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Мне для курсовой работы нужно написать **облачное хранилище данных** (упрощенный вариант Dropbox / Google Drive). В качестве языка обязательно должен быть **NodeJS**. Я создал сервер на Express, и реализовал возможность загрузки файла на сервер, с последующим хранением в БД Mongo->**GridFS**. Но как организовать дерево каталогов, нечто вроде файловой системой. Есть идея использовать одну коллекцию в Mongo для хранения дерева, конечными точками являются документы, содержащие ID файла в GridFS.

1. Велосипед ли это?
2. Есть ли уже реализованный модуль npm  для создания такой иерархии (доступные обвертки для GridFS FUSE не закончены и не дают возможность создавать папки) .

Comment: Мсье, вы не докторскую пишете, а курсовую. Велосипед от вас вполне годен. Дерево организуйте отталкиваясь от требований. Что там может быть? Публичная папка, закрытая папка доступная по авторизации. Допустим 2 папки. Организуйте соотв доступ, чтобы какой нибудь Василий Пупкин изменив запрос не посмотрел пикантные фото Марии Попкиной))) . Это если в условии стоит многопользовательский функционал. Хранение всего дерева в базе, зачем? .Ну понимаю еще путь до каждого документа хранить, чтобы лишний раз рекурсией не искать файлы

Comment: @Димка По функциональным требованиям как раз таки многопользовательский функционал. А использование Heroku, как deploy платформы накладывает ограничения на хранение файлов локально, поэтому и юзается БД mLab

Comment: А обязательно это на Хероку делать? локальный серверок нельзя собрать?

Comment: @Димка препод требовательный